# Laravel 5.4 - Which hash algorithm is used by auth?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I try to write my own register controller but in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#introduction) it is not mentioned which hash algorithm is used by laravel.

Which one is used?

Comment: Did you look here? - https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/hashing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use `bcrypt()` global helper to create hashed password:

```
bcrypt($request->password)
```

Comment: will it give same output, if I use `password_hash($request->password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT)`? Kindly suggest. Thanks.

Comment: BTW I am using your `bcrypt($request->password) ` suggestion in controller file and it returns me an error like `Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\bcrypt()` Kindly suggest what is the issue and how to fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Hash::make($request->password);`

Answer (score 1):

The answer to Your question from the post's title ("Which hash algorithm is used by auth?") can be found on [mnshankar.wordpress.com - Laravel Hash::make() explained](https://mnshankar.wordpress.com/2014/03/29/laravel-hash-make-explained/).

Here is the first sentence from the "**How?**" section of the linked blog post:

> Internally, Hash::make() encrypts using the **bcrypt** function and **Blowfish** algorithm.

Also, You can see on the [Laravel 5.4 docs - Hashing page](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/hashing#introduction) that they say:

> The Laravel Hash facade provides secure **Bcrypt** hashing for storing user passwords.